# How to tear a cloth with an object?

Tags: cloth-simulation

How do I tear this cloth with an object like suzanne the monkey? I tried using a boolean but it did not work. Any suggestions?

[Blender file](https://we.tl/t-kjvSRQcDFe)

[image]

Comment: Cloth modifier should have options for tearing

Answer (score 3):

This is typically a cloth simulation, but with a trick:

[image]

Create the cloth with some subdivision. For the extremities create a vertex group and call it "pin".

[image]

Add a cloth simulation to it.

Change few parameters, like quality steps, tension, bending, and set the pin vertex group as pin group (in the "shape" part):

[image]

Create a second vertex group for the tearing part and move the vertices around for a better effect:

[image]

Create a geometry node modifier, that will remove the tearing part when its position is above X > 1.

[image]

Duplicate the cloth modifier so that the modifier stack looks like this (cloth modifier repeated after the gn modifier):

[image]

Animate Suzan (which is a collision object).

[image]

Comment: OK but he's talking about tearing

Comment: ok... google translate...google translate... ; )